# Height of home bar in Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, gesture, navigationbar, android-navigation-bar

What's the height of the home bar in Android 10 (Q)?
I mean the new home (or multitasking) bar which has been introduced in Android 10 (iOS style). 
We need this size in order to add margin/padding to the bottom to some of our activities/fragments.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely why `WindowInsets` exist - as per the [WindowInsets blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1), `WindowInsets` tell you exactly what insets (i.e., size) the system bars such as the status bar at the top and navigation bar at the bottom are.

By handling window insets, either directly via [`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) on your View as per the [fitsSystemWindows blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) or via the other techniques described in the blog post, your views will get padded in the correct amount on all devices, be it Android 10 or previous versions of Android.